# How do I remove items from a list that meet a criteria

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to identify if an item is even and then removing them from any list and printing the new list

```py
def remove_evens(my_list):
    if item in my_list 0 % 2 == 0:
        # how do I remove the specified items?
    return list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping over list and removing entries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558845/looping-over-list-and-removing-entries-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers = [10, 20, 3, 15, 1000, 60, 16]
removed_evens = list(filter(lambda n: n % 2 != 0, numbers))
print(removed_evens)
```

And function form:

```
def removed_evens(numbers):
    return list(filter(lambda n: n % 2 != 0, numbers))
```

Another logic:

```
def removed_evens(numbers):
    results = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 != 0:
            results.append(number)
    return results
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
def removed_evens(numbers):
    return [number for number in numbers if number % 2 != 0]
```

Or even more minimal:

```
removed_evens = lambda numbers: [number for number in numbers if number % 2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_evens(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        if item %2 == 0:
            my_list.remove(item)
    return my_list
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
remove_evens(my_list)
print(my_list)
```